# gsheet, im stuck with a basic script send emails on cell value

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a Google sheet that will when a cell value reaches less than 10 it will send an email to the contract owner
I'm a newbie with this
row 12 has the value

My script so far

```
function CustomEmail() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var range = sheet.getRange("A2:z50");

var UserData = range.getValues();

for (i in UserData) {

var row = UserData[i];

var name = row[3];

var email = row[1];

var cdate = row[10];

MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Contract", "Hello " + name + ", This contract is expiring " + cdate);
}
}
```

Every IF command I put in just doesn't work, my copy-pasting skills have failed me
can anyone help me please, i don't know if this is a simple issue to fix or I need to learn to code...
thank you in advance if you looked at this and laughed me.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not clear what you are asking. You mention if commands but the code doesn't include any if. If your code throwing and error please include it textually.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this sample code:

```
function CustomEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:z50");

  //get range value as string
  var UserData = range.getDisplayValues();

  for (i in UserData) {
    var row = UserData[i];

    var name = row[3];
    var email = row[1];
    var cdate = row[10];
    var value = parseInt(row[12]); //convert string to int using parseInt()

    if(value<10){
      //send email
      Logger.log(email);
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,"Contract", "Hello " + name + ", This contract is expiring " + cdate);
    }

  }
  
}
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

**What it does?**

1. Get the sheet by its sheet name using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
2. Get range values as string using [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
3. Convert the value string to integer using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
4. Check if value is less than 10, send email to the user